# *HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server ErrorHandler "handlers/exchange.axd_*"

Tags: asp.net, iis

We upgrade our Windows server from Framework v2 to v4, and from iis 6 to iis 8.5. Some sites still use the same framework v2, but one of them get this kind of error :

*HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server ErrorHandler "handlers/exchange.axd_*"
has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list *

This was working in the old server. Now we have Windows 2012 R2

in web.config :

If I run this %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i  I am afraid to change the framework for other sites.

Is there a way to specify the framework in Web.config or IIS ? How could solve this 500 error ? any ideas ?

---

We changed the framework for this site from .NET CLR V.2.05.xxxxx Classic to .Net CLR v4.0.21006 Integrated on IIS.

I imagine that preCondition=IntegratedMode works too, I didn't tested.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that I got the error

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
>   Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

My solution was to

1. Run `cmd` as Administrator end type:

   ```
   dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all
   ```
2. Restart IIS

This solution is from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565006/how-to-register-net-4-5-1-with-iis8-on-windows-10).

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the handlers property in web.config  to

```
preCondition="integratedMode"
```

just go through the link of MSDN with explaination
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx