# Register .Net Framework 4.6 in Windows10 IIS10

Tags: .net, iis, iis-10

How to register .Net Framework 4.6 in my IIS10[windows 10]?

I have VS2017 installed in Windows 10 and IIS shows .Net CLR Version 4.0, could someone help on registering/defaulting to 4.6 in IIS.

[image: IIS .Net CLR Version]

Comment: CLR version 4.0 supports 4.anything (confusingly) so your good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can host your project under any of these pools. This will work fine even if you project is build with .Net framework 4.6

Comment: Your answer is correct. I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/clr#Anchor_0)  - CLR version 4.0 includes 4.0/4.5/4.6/4.7

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, and i am assuming if update .net framework version to 4.6 after ASP.NET IIS registration and you want to update existing app pools to update to 4.6 version. If this is your requirement you just need to perform ASP.NET IIS registration again.

run command prompt from this path

> "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" (64 bit)

or

> "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" for (32 bit)

and execute this command

> aspnet_regiis -i

this will update all exiting this to 4.6 version.

For more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

**Update:**

There is a similar question on stackoverflow however it is about IIS8 on windows 10. Have a look at the question you might get an idea to enable 4.6 from "Turn windows features on or off".

[How to register .Net 4.5.1 with IIS8 on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565006/how-to-register-net-4-5-1-with-iis8-on-windows-10)

Comment: Tried this and i encountered this error   `This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.`

Comment: There is a similar question on stackoverflow however it is about IIS8 on windows 10. Have a look at the question you might get an idea to enable 4.6 from "Turn windows features on or off".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565006/how-to-register-net-4-5-1-with-iis8-on-windows-10

Comment: @KailashRavuri move such to your answer.

Comment: @Kailash Ravuri - I see already accomplished but still my .Net Version shows v4.0 :-(