# How to resolve ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 issue in IIS 10?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis

I am trying to deploye .net Web API in local IIS 10 my 64bit operating system machine.
While browsing from IIS, it is showing below error:

**HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list**

Although one ASP.NET Core web api is running fine in the same IIS.

Comment: Many old threads are out there like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069415/iis-7-httphandler-and-http-error-500-21 so what have you tried? Note that ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core are just like Java and JavaScript, so "one ASP.NET Core web api is running fine in the same IIS" doesn't mean your ASP.NET bits should run.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run cmd as Administrator end type and run the following command:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all
```

Then restart IIS. The method is from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565006/how-to-register-net-4-5-1-with-iis8-on-windows-10). Hope it helps.